# Why do I keep committing suicide?

Tags: path-of-exile

So for some odd reason, every now and then my Flicker Slayer will commit suicide.

I have taken the proper precautions, so I thought:

- Life leech instances imply that the duration of each leech stack should be 5 seconds.  2% per second for a total of 10% maximum life per leech instance.
- Normally leech instances cancel out once you hit full life. But as I am playing Slayer and spec'd into Brutal Fervour, I have overleech, causing life leech instances to run their full duration regardless if I hit full life.
- Bleed procs normally last 5 seconds. However, I am currently using PoB to perform some calculations, and it shows that that bleed procs should only last 3.41 seconds:

[image]

- It's definitely not self-poison. I'm using a Golden Rule jewel that implies poisons/bleeds I inflict will reflect back to myself. But I don't have a single node giving me any chance to inflict poison.

So, at least in theory, I should never be committing suicide. If bleed instances are always lower than leech instances. I've [linked my PoB in case](https://pastebin.com/zKs6kePe) anyone wants to take a look at it. Yet somehow, I still keep committing suicide. This is extremely irritating because it happens when I least expect it. I could be leapslamming my way to the boss and all of a sudden I get hit with a massive bleed degen and die right away.

Why do I keep getting struck by bleed?

Comment: If you have a persistent bleed that is canceled out by leech, is it possible that you're hitting enemies that cannot be leeched from? (similar to the Bloodless passive)

Answer (score 3):

The maximum leech duration is 5 seconds, but only if you're dealing enough damage to reach that amount. It's possible you simply don't deal enough damage and the leech only lasts maybe 2 seconds instead.

Is it for sure bleed degens that kill you? Maybe there are chaos or other ground effects instead, especially if deaths are happening around metamorphs. Having maximum resists is pretty standard for end game and you are just a bit short.

Comment: Do chaos degens also trigger "you committed suicide" console messages? I assumed that only comes from self inflicted damage via Golden rule, scold's, heartbound loop, caustic flasks, etc

Comment: @senpai To be honest I didn't even know such messages existed. So I would say no chaos degens don't.

Answer (score 1):

Check your character sheet and/or gear to see if you have any added chaos damage modifiers.  I think that [Poison](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Poison) may be instant killing you because resistances for this type of damage is typically negative for the average player.  Physical damage and Chaos damage has a chance to inflict Poison, and since it bypasses energy shield.  Given flicker strikes innate mechanic to be everywhere at once, you're probably applying way more Poison stacks to yourself than you can mitigate.